# ExtJS Grid displays date column but not the other

Tags: json, extjs, parsing, grid

I've been having some trouble finding the problem in my code, so thought I'd try to find a second pair of eyes.

Code:

```
var logStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    url: 'inc/interface/config.php?list=messages',
    root: 'logs',
    id: 'ID',
    fields: ['ReceivedAt', 'Message']
});

 var logGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    region: 'center',
    store: logStore,
    autoWidth: true,
    height: 1000,
    colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({ 
                columns:[
            {id: 'received', header: 'Received', dataIndex: 'ReceivedAt', width: 250},
                            {id: 'message', header: 'Logs', dataIndex: 'Message', width: 750}  
                    ]
            }),
});


var mainViewport = new Ext.Viewport({
    layout: 'border',
    items:[logGrid, searchPanel]
});
```

The code above is my interface, and while I am not getting any errors when loading up I just cannot get my data to store in the grid. I believe my store/grid is configured directly, but that's what I'm here for.

Below is the response I get from the store loading my code:

```
{"logs":[
   {"ID":"1","ReceivedAt":"2010-07-07 11:37:42","Message":"Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: Added new forward map from blahhhhhhh to 10.193.blah.blah"},
   {"ID":"2","ReceivedAt":"2010-07-07 11:37:42","Message":"Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: added reverse map from 248.240.blah.blah.in-addr.arpa. to blahhhhhhhh"},
   {"ID":"3","ReceivedAt":"2010-07-07 11:37:42","Message":"Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.193.blah.blah from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (blahhhhhh) via 10.193.blah.blah"}
]}
```

Edited for obvious reasons.

What I did was took out the "log" and just displayed the date and it worked fine; then I tried the log and it failed. The data is stored in mysql like:

Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: Added new forward map from blah.wifi.blah to 10.193.blah.blah

I'm thinking that the JS is having trouble parsing the data or something? What do you guys think?

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the store is loading? I just dropped this in and it ran as I would expect?

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
    var logStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        root: 'logs',
        id: 'ID',
        fields: ['ReceivedAt', 'Message'],
        data: {
            "logs": [{
                "ID": "1",
                "ReceivedAt": "2010-07-07 11:37:42",
                "Message": "Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: Added new forward map from blahhhhhhh to 10.193.blah.blah"
            }, {
                "ID": "2",
                "ReceivedAt": "2010-07-07 11:37:42",
                "Message": "Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: added reverse map from 248.240.blah.blah.in-addr.arpa. to blahhhhhhhh"
            }, {
                "ID": "3",
                "ReceivedAt": "2010-07-07 11:37:42",
                "Message": "Apr 9 00:00:02 dh1 dhcpd: DHCPREQUEST for 10.193.blah.blah from aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff (blahhhhhh) via 10.193.blah.blah"
            }]
        }
    });

    var logGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        region: 'center',
        store: logStore,
        colModel: new Ext.grid.ColumnModel({
            columns: [{
                id: 'received',
                header: 'Received',
                dataIndex: 'ReceivedAt',
                width: 250
            }, {
                id: 'message',
                header: 'Logs',
                dataIndex: 'Message',
                width: 750
            }]
        }),
    });


    var mainViewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [logGrid]
    });

});
```

Try adding a load event on the store to see if it's actually being loaded up properly.

Comment: Yes it's loading up properly as I can see all my information in firebug, plus if I take out the log, the date will display just fine....it has something to do with that pesky log portion..

Comment: I just plugged in what you did and it worked fine.....so I was wrong, but not sure where I should go from here as I'm still kinda new to programming all around.